# UIPageViewController: How To Accomplish State Restoration

Tags: ios11

I would like to know how to go about accomplishing state restoration in an application that uses a UIPageViewController. Given that, at the time of termination, the controller is displaying page n of N and page n has state that is the result of user interactions: How would one go about employing iOS's state restoration mechanisms to save and restore page n?

I have created an exploratory project on [github](https://github.com/verticon/StateRestorationQuestion.git). This project was created via Xcode's Page Based App project template. I have updated it by adding the properties and overrides required to bring state restoration into play. As it currently stands the RootViewController saves the current DataViewController's data (i.e. the month) and restores it upon relaunch. What I would like to achieve is to arrange things such that iOS is invoking the current DataViewController's encodeRestorableState and decodeRestorableState methods.

State restoration occurs in two phases: 1) iOS recreates the view controller hierarchy, and 2) iOS restores the state of each of the view controllers. It is phase 1 wherein I am experiencing the most confusion. In the case of the Page Based App it is the RootViewController's viewDidLoad method that creates the PageViewController. If iOS were to recreate the PageViewController then how would the RootViewController obtain a reference to it? Similar questions apply to iOS's recreation of the DataViewController.